# O porque do uso do break

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu queria saber o porque do uso do break no código(percebi que sem o break, o código é falho):

```
lista = list()
pos = 0
for c in range(0, 5):
    n = int(input('Digite um valor: '))
    if c == 0 or n > lista[-1]:
        lista.append(n)
    else:
        while pos < lista[pos]:
            if n < lista[pos]:
                lista.insert(pos, n)
                break
            pos += 1
print(lista)
```

É um código que coloca os números em ordem numa lista sem o uso do "sort()"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O `break` finaliza o laço de repetição em execução e continua na próxima instrução após esse laço de repetição, seja um laço designado por `while` ou `for`. No seu caso, o `break` está finalizando o laço `while pos < lista[pos]:` e retomando a execução no `for c in range(0, 5):`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

O `break` serve para sair do loop em que ele está. Por exemplo, repare no código abaixo

```
n = 0
while n < 5:
    print(n)
    n += 1

print('Fim do Loop!)
```

se você executar esse código, irá aparecer na tela

```
0
1
2
3
4
Fim do Loop!
```

mas se você adicionar um break como

```
n = 0
while n < 5:
    if n == 3:
        break
    print(n)
    n += 1

print('Fim do Loop!)
```

então o que vai aparecer na tela será

```
0
1
2
Fim do Loop!
```

porque, quando `n==3`, ativou o break, e saiu do loop do `while`

Answer (score 1):

A declaração [`break`](http://excript.com/python/instrucao-break-python.html) serve para interromper a execução de um laço de repetição (`while` e `for`), não sendo executado mais nenhum código abaixo dele que esteja dentro da estrutura de repetição.

Veja abaixo um exemplo:

```
for numero in range(5):

    if numero > 2:
        break

    print(numero)
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/FruitfulDigitalPatterns

No código acima, será impresso apenas os números 0, 1 e 2 porque o `break` interrompe a repetição sem se importar com o resto do código. É exatamente por isso que o Python não permite você escrever código abaixo e no mesmo bloco que ele, já que isso não faria sentido algum.

Essa declaração também é bem semelhante ao *statement* [`continue`](http://excript.com/python/instrucao-continue-python.html), que é uma outra instrução na qual ignora o código abaixo dele, porém continua a execução da estrutura de repetição.

```
for n in range(1000):

    if n > 10: 
        break     # Sai do for loop

    if n % 2 == 0: 
        continue  # Volta para o início do for loop

    print(n)
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/TediousTriflingAddons

Tanto o `break` quanto o `continue` estão presentes em muitas linguagens de programação como Python, Java, JavaScript, Ruby, etc, possuindo a mesma função dentro de estruturas de repetição.

Comment: Mas então o 'break' não iria pular o 'pos +=  1' no meu código?

Comment: Iria não, a declaração `break` **pula** essa linha de código e tudo abaixo dele que esteja no mesmo bloco de repetição ao ser executado dentro do seu bloco `if`.